# Parse JSON array in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

I have managed to extract the following array (which I am dumping to console) from some json.  How can I get and print out the value for one of the elements, i.e. task?

Objective-C:

```
NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:@"row"];
        NSLog(@"array is: %@",array);
```

Console output:

```
array is: {
    0 = 1;
    1 = "send email";
    2 = "with attachment";
    ltask = "with attachment";
    task = "send email";
    userid = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the variable array doesn't seem to be `NSArray` . Does this work for you?

```
    id  array = [dict objectForKey:@"row"];

    if([array isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
        NSLog(@"Value of task %@",array[@"task"]);
    }
```

Comment: Yes that did trick thanks.  Original code for parsing came from different json that did start with an array but in this case, it was a dictionary.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`array` looks like it is actually an `NSDictionary`, so reference the key to get the value for it.

```
NSLog(@"Task: %@", array[@"task"]);
```

Comment: the above objective c prints out the output shown in the console so I think it is valid.  How would I capture and print out just the value of task i.e. "send email".

Comment: My line of code should print out "send email". But if you wanted to use a variable for it, then you could do `id value = array[@"task"];` and then print `value`.

Comment: When I put in the  code in answer, I get red error "Expected method to print dictionary element not found on object of type 'NSArray'"  Same error with id value

Comment: `NSArray` will print to the console using parenthesis `()`, whereas `NSDictionary` will print to the console with curly braces`{}`. The curly braces in your console output tell me that `array` is an `NSDictionary`. Can `array` be either? If so, then you will need to use the `isKindOfClass:` method to handle the different types correctly.

Comment: Ok.  You were right, it was not an array, it was a dictionary.  However I was calling it an array with NSArray *array = ... which seems to have been source of error.  Am up voting your answer and accepting one below by Subbu which caught conflict.

Answer (score 0):

From the log, it looks like the output is an `NSDictionary` object, so to get the value of task key just do this

```
NSDictionary *myDict = dict[@"row"];
NSString *task = myDict[@"task"];
NSLog(@"task = %@", task);
```

if you want to confirm just check the class type using `isKindOfClass:` method

```
if([dict[@"row"] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {

    NSDictionary *myDict = dict[@"row"];
    NSString *task = myDict[@"task"];
    NSLog(@"task = %@", task);

} else if([dict[@"row"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

    NSArray *myArray = dict[@"row"];
    NSDictionary *myDict = myArray[0];
    NSString *task = myDict[@"task"];  
    NSLog(@"task = %@", task);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
        if ([[dictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"row"]) {
            NSObject *objRow = dictionary[@"row"];
            if(objRow){
                if([objRow isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
                     NSArray *arr = (NSArray *)objRow;
                     ....
                }
                if([objRow isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
                     NSDictionary *dic = (NSDictionary *)objRow;
                     ....
                }
            }
        }
```